# Storing current day, month, year as properties in a relation in neo4j using cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, anormcypher

I want to create a relationship in neo4j having properties as day, time, year of the current date.

how can I get the current day,month, year using cypher neo4j??

Answer (score 2):

First, Neo4j doesn't have support for DateTime type.

data

```
CREATE (n1:Node)-[r:RELATIONSHIP {day: 30, month: 9, year: 2015}]->(n2:Node)
```

read

```
MATCH (:Node)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(:Node)
RETURN r.day, r.month, r.year
```

Another approach could be use [GraphAware TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree). Which is Neo4j module for representing time in Neo4j as a tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply store a timestamp, and then deal with it in your application:

`CREATE (n1:Node)-[r:RELATIONSHIP {date:timestamp()}]->(n2:Node)`

As you can see on [Neo4j's documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-timestamp), cypher does actually support `timestamp()` method call in the query, which is the most accurate date you can store, as a `long`